# AIrline Reservation

Tags: java

I am trying to do a basic Java Airline Reservation App. Here is my code, It seems that after I press '1' it is terminating and not running the rest of the code. I am not sure if it is something wrong with my loop or why it is terminating. Please if anyone has any ideas or answers I would love to hear them! thanks

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reservation {

    boolean[] seat = new boolean[11];
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void start() {
        while (true) {
            makeReservation();
        }
    }

    public void makeReservation() {
        System.out.println("Please type 1 for first class and type 2 for economy");

        int section = input.nextInt();

        if (section == 1) {
            firstClassSeat();
        } else {
            economySeat();
        }

    }

    public void firstClassSeat() {

        for (int count = 1; count <= 5; count++) {
            if (seat[count] = false) {
                seat[count] = true;
                System.out.printf("First Class. Seat# %d\n", count);
                break;
            } else if (seat[10] == true) {
                if (seat[5] == true) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("First class is fully booked, would you like an econmy seat");
                    int choice = input.nextInt();
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        firstClassSeat();
                        start();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Next flight is in 3 hours");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void economySeat() {
        for (int count = 6; count <= 10; count++) {
            if (seat[count] = false) {
                seat[count] = true;
                System.out.printf("First Class. Seat# %d\n", count);
                break;
            } else if (seat[10] == true) {
                if (seat[5] == true) {

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Economy is fully booked. Would you like First Class? 1 for Yes 2 for No");
                    int choice = input.nextInt();
                    if (choice == 1) {
                        firstClassSeat();
                        start();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Next flight is in 3 hours");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For one thing, type at: `if (seat[count] = false) {`

Comment: Where is your main method?

Comment: You don't need to call start from your other methods, as it the program execution returns there after exiting the said methods.

Comment: Also, what happens when someone types in '3' for example? I know this is out of the scope of the question, but you should sanitize that input.

Comment: my main method is a seperate class where i new up the reservation class and call the makeReservation() method.

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no need to compare booleans inside an if. `seats[i] == false` is the same as `!seats[i]`.

Nothing is happening because you have an assignment:`if(seat[count]=false` instead of comparison:`if(seat[count]==false`. That's the first error, after fixing that you will start assigning seats.

Next, you're calling `firstClassSeat` inside the same method, when I think you wanted to call `economySeat` (when first class is full). You need to fix the logic behind the checks and economy/first class suggestions.